# How to get actual code of XML form

Tags: php, xml

I'm working on accessibility. I found some issues while inspecting in Chrome browser but I'm not getting the actual code in VS for XML files.

Comment: Hi and welcome to JSE! Please add more details to your question: what is the exact issue? which code are you looking for (PHP, JS, HTML…)? And what have you found? Are you working in admin or in site? And so on…

Comment: Welcome to JSE, @Kumar.  I am afraid your question is too vague and not yet a good fit for our Q&A and would be justifiably closed as "Needs details or clarity".  Please [edit] your question to better explain what is happening for you.  Volunteers will need enough detail to reproduce the problem themselves so that they can confidently offer support.  Please take our [tour].